# Read a topic with multiple events

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

What should be done in a Spark Structured Streaming job so that it can read a multi event Kafka topic?

I am trying to read a topic that has multiple type of events. Every event may have difference schema. How does a streaming job determine the type of event or which schema of the event to use ?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Dataframes are always bytes. You use a UDF to deserialize the key/value columns.

For example, assuming data is JSON, you first cast bytes to string, then you can use `get_json_object` to extract/filter specific fields.

If data is in other format, then you could use Kafka record headers added by the producer (you'll need to add those in your own producer code) to designate what event type each record is, then filter based on those, and add logic for processing different sub-dataframes. Or you could wrap binary data in a more consistent schema such as CloudEvents spec, which includes a `type` field and nested binary content, which needs further deserialized.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. I am trying to read a topic that has multiple type of events. Every event may have difference schema. How does a streaming job determine the type of event or which schema of the event to use ?

Comment: I understood fine, but thanks for clarifying. It doesn't. As answered, **your app** does via whatever you have access to. For example, a nested `type` field in JSON, an Avro/Protobuf union type definition, or `headers` entry in the dataframe. You need to use SparkSQL `filter` multiple times to get specific typed dataframes